# Grails Where Query With Multiple Sort Fields

Tags: sorting, grails

I can't find an example in the doc and I would prefer to use the nifty "where" functionality instead of the "criteria builder" functionality.

I have my "where" query:

```
def query = Nhrdist.where
{
    nhrdistPidm == pidm
    nhrdistFundCode == fundCode
    nhrdistCategoryCode == 'A'
    nhrdistAcctCode in ['20L0', '20L2', '20L3', '20L4', '20L5']
    nhrdistTransDate in fiscalYearBeginDate..fiscalYearEndDate
}
```

And the following works when I sort by one field:

```
def results = query.list(sort:'nhrdistAcctCode')
```

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to sort by two fields. I would like to sort by nhrdisAcctCode first, and then sort by nhrdistTransDate. I can't find any examples on http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries

Can someone:

1. Provide me an example that shows how to sort with multiple fields OR
2. Belittle me and point out in the doc where it says I can't do this OR
3. Belittle me and give me the link to a StackOverflow page that answers my question OR
4. Tell me to quit my whining and just use a Criteria Builder query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def results = query.order( 'nhrdistAcctCode' )
                   .order( 'nhrdistTransDate', 'desc' ) // or asc
                   .list()
```

should do it.

Here `order()` is called on `DetachedCriteria` ( where query ) as a builder pattern.